# How to use Conditions in switch case in c++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

Is there any way I can use a switch-case statement based on the answer of condition?

For example: if a percentage is greater than 90 then by using the switch statement, it should print grade A?

Comment: No, use `if ... else if ... else if ... else ...` instead.

Comment: but my teacher said to do that with switch statement

Comment: The only thing you can do with a switch here is switching over a boolean condition: `switch(value > 90) { case true: ...; break; case false: ... break; }`

Comment: If you have a formula to convert your number with big range (0..100) in a number with small range (n / 10, so range is no only 0..10), you might do it.

Comment: You cannot do conditions in a switch statement. You could do `case 90: case 91: case 92: case 93: case 94: case 95: case 96: case 97: case 98: case 99: case 100: ...` Maybe that is what your teacher meant? Or you could just have an incompetent teacher, it happens. Or you could have just misunderstood.

Comment: @john: That is my thought as well. Though I'd say that writing out the explicit numbers makes no sense. So rather use an `else if` chain.

Comment: gcc has [case ranges extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html) (so no valid/portable C++).

Comment: @ProBoy Is it a requirement that you use the `switch`/`case` construct to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main()
{
int n;

std::cout<<"Enter Mark:";
std::cin>>n;

n=n>90;

switch(n)
{
case 1:
    std::cout<<"Grade A";
    break;
case 0:
    std::cout<<"Grade B";
    break;
}

return 0;
}
```

or if you have more than two

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

// <50 is c , 50 - 90 is b, >90 is a

int main()
{
int n;

std::cout<<"Enter Mark:";
std::cin>>n;

n=(n>50?(n>90?1:2):3);

switch(n)
{
case 1:
    std::cout<<"Grade A";
    break;
case 2:
    std::cout<<"Grade B";
    break;
case 3:
    std::cout<<"Grade C";
    break;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hard to see how that's an improvement over `if else if else`

Comment: better dont use an `int` for a boolean value

Comment: @john -- it's an improvement because it meets the requirements in the question. Yes, those requirements are artificial, but that doesn't mean they can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double physics,chemistry,biology,computer,math,totalMarks,obtainMarks,percentage;
    char grade;
    cout<<"Enter Total Marks=";
    cin>>totalMarks;
    cout<<"Enter Marks of Physics=";
    cin>>physics;
    cout<<"Enter Marks of chemistry=";
    cin>>chemistry;
    cout<<"Enter Marks of biology=";
    cin>>biology;
    cout<<"Enter Marks of computer=";
    cin>>computer;
    cout<<"Enter Marks of Mathematics=";
    cin>>math;
    obtainMarks=physics+chemistry+biology+computer+math;
    percentage=(obtainMarks/totalMarks)*100;
    grade=percentage>=90?'A':(percentage>=80?'B':(percentage>=70?'C':(percentage>=60?'D':(percentage>=40?'E':'F'))));

    switch(grade)
    {
        case 'A' : cout<<"you have got A grade";
        break;
        case 'B': cout<<"you have got B grade";
        break;
        case 'C': cout<<"you have got C grade";
        break;
        case 'D': cout<<"you have got D grade";
        break;
        case 'E': cout<<"you have got E grade";
        break;
        case 'F': cout<<"you have got F grade";
        break;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

done!

Comment: Simpler to replace the switch with `cout << "You have got " << grade << " grade"`